# What exactly do this JQuery script on this jsTree element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2, jstree

I am absolutly new in JavaScript and even more in JQuery.

I have some problem to understand what exactly do a JQuery script, I try to explain the situation.

In a JSP page that use Struts2 tag library (it is only a tag library that wrap standard JQuery component) I have something like this:

```
<s:form id="treeForm" >
    <s:hidden name="idFolder" id="folderId"/>
    <s:hidden name="event"/>
    <s:hidden name="groupId"/>
    <s:hidden name="fileUrlCon"/>
    <s:hidden name="titleEvent"/>
    <s:hidden name="folderPath" id="folderPath"/>

    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="33.3%">
                <sjt:tree id="treeId2" jstreetheme="default"
                          rootNode="root" openAllOnLoad="false"
                          childCollectionProperty="children"
                          nodeTitleProperty="title"
                          nodeIdProperty="id"
                        >
                </sjt:tree>
            </td>

            <td width="66.6%">
                <s:form >
                            <sj:div id="resultEvents" href="%{loadFolderTechId}"
                                    formIds="treeForm"
                                    class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                                    loadingText=" "
                                    onBeforeTopics="before"
                                    onCompleteTopics="complete"
                                    deferredLoading="true"
                                    reloadTopics="reloadEvents"
                                    >
                            </sj:div>
                    <s:submit action="projectCreationAction"/>
                </s:form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#treeId2").bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
            if (!isNaN(data.rslt.obj.attr("id"))) {
                //foglia quindi block

                document.getElementById("folderId").value = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
                document.getElementById("folderPath").value = '';

                $.publish('reloadEvents');


            } else {

                document.getElementById("folderPath").value = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");

                $.publish('reloadEvents');
            }

        })
        window.setTimeout(
                function() {
                    $("#treeId2").jstree("open_node", $('#root'));
                },
                1000);
    });

</script>
```

The **sjt:tree** tag wrap and is based on the JQuery **jsTree** plugin, this: http://www.jstree.com/docs/config/ and should work in the same way generating a tree.

It work and correctly generate the tree into my JSP page.

My dubts are related to the following JQuery script operating on this tree:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#treeId2").bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
        if (!isNaN(data.rslt.obj.attr("id"))) {
            //foglia quindi block

            document.getElementById("folderId").value = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
            document.getElementById("folderPath").value = '';

            $.publish('reloadEvents');


        } else {

            document.getElementById("folderPath").value = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");

            $.publish('reloadEvents');
        }

    })
    window.setTimeout(
            function() {
                $("#treeId2").jstree("open_node", $('#root'));
            },
            1000);
});
```

What exactly do? I am trying to analyze it by myself and I think that it do:

1) First it select the element having **id=#treeId2** so it select my entire tree.

2) Then the **bind()** function attach an handler to an event for the elements. So in this case the handled event is the selection of a node of my tree.

3) In this case I think that the event handler is represented by the following definied function that take 2 input parameters. Now my doubt is: what exactly are the 2 parameters **event** and **data**?

I think that the **event** parmeter represent the **select_node.jstree** event, is it true?
And what represent the **data** paramether?

And what exactly do:

```
document.getElementById("folderId").value = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
document.getElementById("folderPath").value = '';
```

What represent the **document.getElementById("folderId")** and **document.getElementById("folderPath")** ?

Can you explain what exactly do this script?

Comment: The two lines both fetch elements that have `id="folderId"` and `id="folderPath"`. I presume they are input fields, but you need to show all your code/HTML.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie oh yes these are a form inputs fields

Comment: The first line sets the value of the input to the value obtained from data (selected node by the look of it). The second blanks out the second input. Please show all the code though :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have edit the original post adding the others code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines set hidden field data values so that when the form is submitted those selected values are posted back.

The two fields referenced are these:

```
<s:hidden name="idFolder" id="folderId"/>
<s:hidden name="folderPath" id="folderPath"/>
```

This gets the selected data value from your tree and stores it in the `folderId` field.

```
document.getElementById("folderId").value = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
```

This one clears the folder path to blank:

```
document.getElementById("folderPath").value = '';
```

There is a submit later in the code, that is presumably activated by "something":

```
 <s:submit action="projectCreationAction"/>
```

**Note:** I am not familiar with struts2, so do not know how forms are submitted but it looks like the `$.publish('reloadEvents');` code triggers it as `reloadEvents` is mentioned in the same form HTML

Comment: Ok, but when is submitted the form?

Comment: Added more details based on what I guess is causing the submit (the `$.publish()` calls).

Comment: so do you think that the $.publish() calls automatically sumbitt into the script?

Comment: Based on the available evidence, yes. The only clue is the nested `s:form` and the use of `reloadTopics="reloadEvents"`. You need a struts2 expert to confirm this though (never used it myself) :)